# Sorting text out in a way that i cant explain but show

Tags: vb.net

im creating a program that allows me to take information from a text doc(that was easy) But i want it to sort it. let me show u whats in the doc

```
  ==================================================
  Contry            : USA
  User Name         : quan123
  realname          : quan
  Created Time      : 9/14/2085 1:35:00 AM
  ==================================================

  ==================================================
  Contry            : Canada
  User Name         : thecat
  realname          : sam
  Created Time      : 10/19/2076 2:54:53 AM
  ==================================================
```

So what im trying to do is to take all the user names and put it in a different text box. I have no clue on how to do it. i tried to make a function that cuts some of the text out but only does the first one on the top of the doc for example

This is the function

```
    Function Cut(ByVal sInhalt As String, ByVal sText As String, ByVal stext2 As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim c() As String
    Dim c2() As String
    c = Split(sInhalt, sText)
    c2 = Split(c(1), stext2)
    Cut = c2(0)
    End Function
```

To use the the function

```
 Dim suser As String = Cut(TextBox2.Text, "User Name         :", vbNewLine
```

But as i said, this only gets one of the usernames in the doc and its the first one it finds. I want all of the usernames in the doc

Comment: Use a `For Each` loop to loop through all the lines on the text...

Comment: @JoshPart im sorry for my lack of knowledge but how would i do that

Comment: I think you meant to ping @JoshPart   You lost me at `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: @Plutonix my apologies

Comment: @Zeltronplayz just posted an answer explaining

Comment: @JoshPart Thx for helping

Comment: Are you using VB.NET or VB6. 
`On error Resume Next` was a primarily a VB6 command

Comment: @logixologist im using vb.net

Comment: @JoshPart it only grabed the last users user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `For Each` loop to extract all the names from the lines of the textbox.

```
For Each line as String in TextBox2.Lines
    If line.Contains("User Name") Then
        TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text & Cut(line, "User Name         : ", vbNewLine) & vbNewLine
    End If
Next
```

If you are using `.NET Framework 3.5` or above, you can eliminate the need of the `If` using `Linq`

```
For Each line as String in TextBox2.Lines.Where(Function(l) l.Contains("User Name"))
    TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text & Cut(line, "User Name         : ", vbNewLine) & vbNewLine
Next
```

BTW you are missing a trailing space on the second parameter of your function: you should send `"User Name         : "`; as you're sending it now, it leaves a leading space on the `suser` variable

Comment: This did not work it only got the last users name @JoshPart

Comment: How exactly do you want to store the user names? Or what do you do with them after you retrieve them? The code I posted gets all the user names, but as long as you just asign it to the same variable, each loop will overwrite the previous value.

Comment: For Each line As String In TextBox2.Lines.Where(Function(l) l.Contains("User Name"))
            TextBox3.Text = Cut(line, "User Name         : ", vbNewLine)
            ''' Do whatever you need to do with the user...
        Next                                                                                                               thats how im running it right now. and its showing up as the last users username

Comment: I edited my code; you need string concatenation. I assume you want each name on a separate line in the textb box